# Angular UI Tree: A tree with two types. A node cannot be dropped into empty node

Tags: angularjs

I have an example (http://plnkr.co/edit/u3JiQHSfBJyTnCfqGauK?p=preview) where I have a **angular ui tree** with two different types (folder and file). In the code I'm implementing 'accept' to allow dropping items only to appropriate targets.
First folder "folder0" is empty. And I cannot drag and drop any other folder into it.
If a folder has subfolders then dropping works fine.

Comment: [Angular UI Tree](http://jimliu.github.io/angular-ui-tree/)

Comment: The latest version has drop target for empty nodes enabled

Comment: I've just tried the updated code. I don't see the problem fixed. [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/vPaKiR04dYpkOmfs8FpQ?p=preview)